# How to show overflowing text with animation?(Javascript - HTML - CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Is there any way of recognizing text **overflow** with JS and show the **overflowing text in an animated way**? For example, moving the text to the left, like the spotify widget:

[image: Spotify web Widget]

Comment: Have a look at thsi.. http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/ if a plugin is fine with you

Comment: You can also try comparing the `length` of the String and if it is more than `x` (depends on your requirement) then replace the last three characters of the String by `...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to confirm a text requires scrolling if you use "scrollWidth > clientWidth " of the container - assuming it has overflow:hidden and you take margin, padding and borders into account. Look at [element dimensions](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/elementdimensions.html) for a basic overview. To scroll the text you just have to give it a negative margin-left, or use a DIV with position:absolute inside a DIV with position:relative and give the inner one a negative left value (CSS).